# How to obtain correct dimension from Camera2 and ImageReader?

Tags: android, android-camera2

In my Android application, I use Camera2 API to allow the user to take a snapshot. The code mostly is straight out of standard Camera2 sample application.

When the image is available, it is obtained by calling `acquireNextImage` method:

```
 public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
     mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
 }
```

In my case, when I obtain the width and height of the `Image` object, it reports it as 4160x3120. However, in reality, it is 3120x4160. The real size can be seen when I dump the buffer into a jpg file:

```
 ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
 byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
 buffer.get(bytes);
 // Dump "bytes" to file
```

For my purpose, I need the correct width and height. Wondering if the width and height are getting swapped because the sensor orientation is 90 degrees.

If so, I can simply swap the dimensions if I detect that the sensor orientation is 90 or 270. I already have this value:

```
  mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
```

I feel this is a general problem and not specific to my code. Regards.

Edit:

Turns out the image size reported is correct. Jpeg image metadata stores a field called "Orientation." Most image viewers know how to interpret this value.

Comment: I have edited my original post. The reported dimensions are correct. There is a field called orientation that is also saved as part of jpeg metadata that I had ignored.